# How can I install qwtplot3D in QT5 with mingw

Tags: qt5

I want to know the configuration. Can any one help me?I have tried like this:
in qwtplot3d.pro
chage 
win32:TEMPLATE =vclib 
to
win32:TEMPLATE=lib
change 
CONFIG+=qt warn_on opengl thread zlib debug 
to
CONFIG+=qt warn_on opengl thread zlib release
add #include in qwt3d_functions.cpp

but it does not work

Comment: The qt version is 5.4

Comment: Could you please put the pro-file into code-format? And could you please post the error you get from qmake?